# How to use WebKitFormBoundary data as your payload when posting to the server with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Hopefully, my question makes sense, but I'll try to explain it better here.

So, this is the post request data that was sent to the server when I analyzed the post request headers:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4q6NLNtlzAsbRBY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_type"

product
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4q6NLNtlzAsbRBY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="utf8"

✓
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4q6NLNtlzAsbRBY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"

36110014939287
------WebKitFormBoundaryq4q6NLNtlzAsbRBY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add"
```

I have two issues here. I am trying to use this data to send as my payload in a post request like a dictionary, but I'm not really sure how I would do this as I've never seen anything like this before.

Second, I see there is a hidden value for the "utf8" name, so how would I go about decoding that value and converting it back to a string.

Again, hopefully this makes sense and I'm sorry if it doesn't - I will do my best to respond to any follow up questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ajax use  **contentType: false;**
or

use  enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in form

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```